# Adding new row in excel using macro (button)

Tags: vba, excel, button

I am completely new to macros/VBA. All I am trying to do is to create a button which should add new row. I also want to add data to the new row when the row is created using the button.
I copied the code from somewhere and I works fine there but when I try to run it, it gives me error = "Method 'Range' of object '_Worksheet' failed"
I believe it is due to the code line:

```
last_row_with_data = the_sheet.Range(A65536).End(x1Up).Row
```

The person has done it using simple sub/method but I am doing it with a button

Full code is below:

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()

Dim the_sheet As Worksheet
Dim table_list_object As ListObject
Dim table_object_row As ListRow
Set the_sheet = Sheets("Sheet1")
Set table_list_object = the_sheet.ListObjects(1)
Set table_object_row = table_list_object.ListRows.Add

table_object_row.Range(1, 1).Value = "12324"

last_row_with_data = the_sheet.Range(A65536).End(x1Up).Row

the_sheet.Range("B" & last_row_with_data) = "Title Name"
the_sheet.Range("C" & last_row_with_data) = "Ref Number"

End Sub
```

I don't know whats wrong with code because I am completely new to macros. Anyone please correct the error?

Comment: `xlUp` NOT `x1up` :-D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
last_row_with_data = the_sheet.Range(A65536).End(x1Up).Row
```

should be

```
last_row_with_data = the_sheet.Range(A65536).End(xlUp).Row
```

to make it run cleaner, you can use:

```
last_row_with_data = the_sheet.Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
```

Comment: Many thanks for the help. Really helpful.
I don't know what's the difference in these two statements but all I know is it does the job I want to do.
Is there anyway I can copy the formulas from the above row and insert it in the new row which I am creating?
Thanks in advance

Comment: Something like `the_sheet.Range("A" & last_row_with_data - 1).EntireRow.Copy` and then `the_sheet.Range("A" & last_row_with_data).PasteSpecial` should do that.